# React native project on Android 9 change to 8.1 problem

Tags: react-native

**I have a project that compiles for android 9 (sdk 28.0.3) but I have a phone version 8.1 (27.0.3) and would like to be able to compile on my phone. Currently, everything compiles well for me on another phone in android 9.0**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {

            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**when I try to change to 27.0.3 (android 8.1) I get such a message from the console**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVSTy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache of the project

```
Clear watchman watches: npm watchman watch-del-all
Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```